# cannot kill process in FreeBSD

Tags: process, freebsd

I have a script in FreeBSD 10.1 release, it's purpose is to monitor another process and keep the process alive.
When I try to kill itself, it always fail.
I try killall [name | pid]; pkill -9 [name]; service watchtas stop, none of them work.
Below is my script, please advise the solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/rc.subr
prog="Thin-Agent WatchDog"
TAS_BIN="/etc/supermicro/tas-freebsd.x86_64"
TAS_LOG="/etc/supermicro/tas_system_crush.log"
monitor=1
name="watchtas"
rcvar=${name}_enable
command=/etc/rc.d/{$name}
start_cmd="watchdog"
stop_cmd="stop_watching"
load_rc_config $name


recover_tas() {
  $TAS_BIN -agent start-service
  RETVAl=$?
  return $RETVAL
}

stop_watching() {
  monitor=0
}

watchdog() {
    while [ $monitor == 1 ]
    do
        tas_count=`ps -x | grep tas-freebsd.x86_64 | grep -v grep | wc -l | sed 's/ *//g'`

        if [ $tas_count -eq 0 ]; then
            timestamp=`date`
            echo "[$timestamp]TAS shutdown unexpectedly, restarting TAS now..." >> $TAS_LOG
            echo $?
            recover_tas
        else
            sleep 10
        fi
    done
}

run_rc_command "$1"
```

Comment: It's solve by /bin/kill -s HUP [pid]. Don't know if there is another kill way by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your start-up script fails in a couple of respects. `service watchtas start` does not return to the command line because the daemon process does not detach. `service watchtas stop` does not work as required because the variable `monitor` is local to the executing script.

I would separate the start-up script and the watchdog code into separate files and use [daemon(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon) to monitor the watchdog.

The `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` start-up script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.subr
name="watchtas"
rcvar=${name}_enable
pidfile="/var/run/${name}.pid"
command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
command_args="-c -f -P ${pidfile} -r /usr/local/sbin/${name}"
load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

The `/usr/local/sbin/watchtas` watchdog code would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
TAS_BIN="/etc/supermicro/tas-freebsd.x86_64"
TAS_LOG="/etc/supermicro/tas_system_crush.log"

recover_tas() {
  $TAS_BIN -agent start-service
  RETVAl=$?
  return $RETVAL
}

while true
do
    tas_count=`ps -x | grep tas-freebsd.x86_64 | grep -v grep | wc -l | sed 's/ *//g'`

    if [ $tas_count -eq 0 ]; then
        timestamp=`date`
        echo "[$timestamp]TAS shutdown unexpectedly, restarting TAS now..." >> $TAS_LOG
        echo $?
    recover_tas
    else
        sleep 10
    fi
done
```

It seems you have a daemon watching a daemon watching a daemon.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for your answer.